# SharePoint 2010 SPListItem.FieldValues returned wrong timeofday

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, when I created a datetime filed to a custom list, the value shown in the list view under Modified is:

Date : 18/6/2013 13:00

But yet when I programmatically access the field which I assume is SPListItem.FieldValue["Date"], it returned:

18/6/2013 4:00:00

What should I do to make to display the correct time? Or is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP 2010 stores date list column values in UTC time (not local time). When you retrieve it programmatically (via `SPListItem`), it converts the value to your local timezone. You can always use the .NET `DateTime` methods, such as `ToUniversalTime()` to convert back to UTC which *should* match what you see in the UI.